# gnuplot: "plot for" and multiple using statements

Tags: gnuplot

I have multiple data files in a directory and want to generate one plot from all of them.
Every datafile has an own columnhead (set key autotitle columnhead).

It works when I plot one graph (one "using") statement. If I have multiple using statements, only the first is plotted correctly, for the others only the first datapoint is processed (only one label, one yerrorbars, but 5 linepoints)

gnuplot statements:

```
set key autotitle columnhead                  
files = system("echo $(ls *.csv)")

plot for [i=1:words(files)] word(files,i) using 0:2:xtic(1) with lp ,\
'' using 0:2:2 with labels font ',8' offset 1,0.5 notitle "",\ 
'' using 0:2:3 with yerrorbars lt -1 lc rgb 'grey' title ""
```

If I only plot labels or only yerrorbars they are also correct, it's only broken when I'm using multiple "using" statements with "plot for".

Anybody have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Gnuplot version: 4.6.5

thanks a lot
(gnuplot is driving me crazy)

Comment: I don't quite get what you want to achieve. Could you try to abstract and give an example of what your `.csv` files contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for` iteration applies only to the first command. In order to iterate also in the following commands, you must repeat the iteration:

```
set key autotitle columnhead                  
files = system("echo $(ls *.csv)")

plot for [f in files] f using 0:2:xtic(1) with lp ,\
     for [f in files] f using 0:2:2 with labels font ',8' offset 1,0.5 notitle "",\ 
     for [f in files] f using 0:2:3 with yerrorbars lt -1 lc rgb 'grey' title ""
```

Note, that in your case (you don't need the iteration index `i`) you can directly iterate over the files.